# Moving image down screen with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to move my image down the screen from the top left to the bottom left. I call two functions when the body loads:

```
window.onload = function() {
MoveRight();
MoveDown();
};
```

I then retreive the width and height of the clients browser window (to ensure the animation stops when it reaches the sides of the window):

```
document.body.style.height = height;
document.body.style.width = width;
```

The function "MoveDown()" is this:

```
function MoveDown(){
for(var i = 0; i < ; i++)
    {
       document.getElementById("Amanda").style.top=+i;
    }
}
```

For some reason when I load the webpage, the image just sits in the top left. I had hoped the for loop would increment the "top" value by 1px every time, until such time that it was touching the bottom of the window when it would stop.

If it helps, the image position is set to relative with left and top both set to 0px.

If anyone could help it would be great.

*I collect the width as I want the image to move diagonally but figured that if I got moving down figured out I could easily change the code to make it go sideways at the same time.

Comment: Any reason not to set it to absolute and give it a bottom of 0?

Comment: Yes, because I want the animation, hence to loop of incrementing the pixel by 1 every time it runs. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not moving is most likely (depending on browser) because you're not setting the units. Try

```
document.getElementById("Amanda").style.top=i+"px";
```

However, you'll find that it jumps straight down rather than animating. The reason is your loop executes all in one go without giving the browser a chance to redraw. There are a number of ways of getting around this, but one simple one would be like this

```
function MoveDown() {
    var i=0;
    function step() {
       document.getElementById("Amanda").style.top=i+"px";
       i++;
       if (i<=100) setTimeout(step,10);
    }
    step();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `position: absolute` or `position: relative` (or `position: fixed`) as styling for your image?
Asking this because `top` applies only to positioned elements (and by default elements have `position: static` which is they are not explicitly positioned).
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

On rereading your question, this loop of yours looks like an endless loop. Consider adding a stop rule for it, or as suggested in the comments - if you do not need some kind of sliding animation, just put css rule for `bottom: 0`

Comment: I have it set to "relative" with top set to 0px. Would the for loop not stop when it reaches "height"? I have height defined as the browser window height. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` (I can never remember) with some interval and a function that increments the top value every time it runs. Then cancel the timeout/interval when the image reaches it's destination!

Comment: Thanks Gonzofish. My code for the function MoveDown() is like: http://pastebin.com/Tkqew4Qx but is still not working. I added a delay using SetTimeout.

Just to confirm the image is not moving anywhere, it stays in the top left hand corner